# What is the cleanest way to duplicate base/parent.pm's functionality for non-object perl modules?

Tags: perl, refactoring, module

I'm not thinking too clearly right now and possibly overlooking something simple. I've been thinking about this for a while and been searching, but can't really think of any sensible search queries anymore that would lead me to what i seek.

In short, I'm wondering how to do module inheritance, in the way base.pm/parent.pm do it for object-oriented modules; only for Exporter-based modules.

A hypothetical example of what i mean:

Here's our script. It originally loaded Foo.pm and called baz() from it, but baz() has a terrible bug (as we'll soon see), so we're using Local/Patched/Foo.pm now which should fix the bug. We're doing this, because in this hypothetical case we cannot change Foo (it is a cpan module under active development, you see), and it is huge (seriously).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# use Foo qw( baz [... 100 more functions here ...] );
use Local::Patched::Foo qw( baz [... 100 more functions here ...] );
baz();
```

Here's Foo.pm. As you can see, it exports baz(), which calls qux, which has a terrible bug, causing things to crash. We want to keep baz and the rest of Foo.pm though, without doing a ton of copy-paste, especially since they might change later on, due to Foo still being in development.

```
package Foo;
use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw( baz [... 100 more functions here ...] );
sub baz { qux(); }
sub qux { print 1/0; }            # !!!!!!!!!!!!!
[... 100 more functions here ...]
1;
```

Lastly, since Foo.pm is used in MANY places, we do not want to use Sub::Exporter, as that would mean copy-pasting a bandaid fix to all those many places. Instead we're trying to create a new module that acts and looks like Foo.pm, and indeed loads 99% of its functionality still from Foo.pm and just replaces the ugly qux sub with a better one.

What follows is what such a thing would look like if Foo.pm was object-oriented:

```
package Local::Patched::Foo;
use parent 'Foo';
sub qux { print 2; }
1;
```

Now this obviously will not work in our current case, since parent.pm just doesn't do this kinda thing.

Is there a clean and simple method to write Local/Patched/Foo.pm (using any applicable CPAN modules) in a way that would work, short of copying Foo.pm's function namespace manually?

Comment: The moral of the story here is you save yourself lots of pain later on if you call all of your library functions as `Class->foo`, rather than `Class::foo`. :)

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean with that, as i am doing neither here. :o I'm really just trying to find what the question title says, a sane equivalent of parent/base.pm in the functional world. (Since i do not really like object-oriented programming. ;) )

Comment: @mithaldu: will clarify in my post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding in yet another way to monkey-patch `Foo`'s `qux` function, this one without any manual typeglob manipulation.

```
package Local::Patched::Foo;
use Foo (); # load but import nothing

sub Foo::qux {
    print "good qux";
}
```

This works because Perl's packages are always mutable, and so long as the above code appears after loading `Foo.pm`, it will override the existing `baz` routine.  You might also need `no warnings 'redefine';` to silence any warnings.

Then to use it:

```
use Local::Patched::Foo;
use Foo qw( baz );

baz();  # calls the patched qux() routine
```

You could do away with the two `use` lines by writing a custom import method in `Local::Patched::Foo` as follows:

```
# in the Local::Patched::Foo package:

sub import {
    return unless @_;             # return if no imports
    splice @_, 0, 1, 'Foo';       # change 'Local::Patched::Foo' to 'Foo'
    goto &{ Foo->can('import') }; # jump to Foo's import method
}
```

And then it is just:

```
use Local::Patched::Foo qw( baz );

baz();  # calls the patched qux()
```

Comment: This is missing the whole Exporter song and dance and as such won't work as is, however i have to say that i like the patch module like this a lot more: http://gist.github.com/519673 Thanks. :)

Comment: OK, updated to include the fixed original code, and a new import method if you want that functionality.  Also, keep in mind that the body of `qux` is in the `Local::Patched::Foo` package, so using `__PACKAGE__` there will not return `Foo`.  You could change this by either entering the `Foo` package before declaration, or right inside the sub's body.  Not that it matters in most cases.

Comment: Wow, the import function is slick. There's still something you need to fix though: require Foo; is a runtime directive, while sub Foo::qux [...] is a compile time directive, and thus overridden as it executes before the require. I think "use Foo qw();" is the right solution there, or a BEGIN block.

Answer (score 4):

If it's one subroutine you want to override, you can do some monkey patching:

`*Foo::qux = \&fixed_qux;`

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest or best solution, but for a temporary stopgap until upstream fixes the bug in `qux`, it should do.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to simply replace the sub reference. if you can install it, use the [Sub::Override](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub::Override) CPAN module. Absent that, this will do:

```
package Local::Patched::Foo;

use Exporter;

sub baz { print "GOOD baz!\n" };

sub import() {
    *Foo::baz = \&Local::Patched::Foo::baz;
}

1;
```

Comment: This (with some modifications: http://gist.github.com/519673 ) looks to be pretty nice. Can i ask why you replace import like that?

Comment: @mithaldu - just another way of ensuring your substitution will be executed upon "`use`". I like your way beter.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hijacking Alexandr's answer (which was correct, but incomplete), here's a solution under separate copy:

---

```
package Foo;
use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw(foo bar baz qux);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'all' => [ qw(foo bar baz qux) ],
    'all_without_qux' => [ qw(foo bar baz) ],
);

sub foo { 'foo' }
sub bar { 'bar' }
sub baz { 'baz' }
sub qux { 'qux' }

1;
```

---

```
package Foo::Patched;
use Foo qw(:all_without_qux);
use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw( foo bar baz qux );

sub qux { 'patched qux' }

1;
```

---

```
package main;
use Foo::Patched;

print qux();
```

You can also `use Foo;` in your program, *as long as you use it before `Foo::Patched`*, or you will overwrite the patched qux with the original broken version.

There are a few morals here (at least they are IMHO):

1. don't export into the caller's namespace without being explicitly told to (i.e. keep `@EXPORT` empty, and use `@EXPORT_OK` and `%EXPORT_TAGS` to allow the caller to specify exactly what they want. Or alternatively, don't export at all, and use fully-qualified names for all library functions.
2. Write your libraries so that the functions are called OO-style: `Foo->function` rather than `Foo::function`. This makes it much easier to override a function by using the standard `use base` syntax we all know and love, without having to mess around with monkeypatching symbol tables or manipulating exporter lists.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I do appreciate it, but you overlooked a subtle problem. In the original code Foo::baz() calls Foo::qux(), and script.pl called Foo::baz(). This is a problem, since the bug is in Foo::qux(), which may not even be exporter. So to fix it one would have to patch both baz() and qux(), which i wish to avoid. :)

Comment: @mithaldu: well that's why using fully-qualified names without OO syntax is a bad thing, see point #2 :)

Comment: Good point on @export there, i was using it with the right thing in mind, but the wrong name. As for fully-qualified names, yeah, they're a possible solution. However I am looking to apply this to something i essentially do not have control over, so i can not change this even if i wanted to. :) (Also, I have seen a project that used Exporter nowhere and fully-qualified sub names EVERYWHERE. I can tell you it was not pretty or maintainable in the least. ;) )

Comment: Another point: Especially because this sort of symbol table manipulation should not be happening in every module i was looking for a module that already did this.

Comment: @mithaldu: Sub::Override as per DVK's answer will do it for you in the meantime while you are dealing with legacy code.  (To clarify, you only have to patch qux once, not everywhere it is called. Once it is patched once it is patched for everyone; the original version of qux is totally unreachable.)

Comment: If I may add one item to the morals list is that one should be trying to avoid a solution that _looks_ pretty or stable. Overriding subs in a module should be a temporary measure, thus I prefer to have a solution that screams "temporary hack", so as not to forget that the focus should be on fixing the upstream module Foo.

Comment: Ether: I was talking about separate .pl/.cgi files, not just separate modules. You'd be right in the latter case but my situation isn't that nice, i'm afraid. :)

Comment: szbalint: While i agree with the sentiment, i find it kind of odd that this sort of thing is perfectly *fine* in the object-oriented world, but bad in the functional world.

Comment: @mithaldu: patching symbol table entries is a hack and always will be.  Overriding methods in the OO world is one of the intended usecases of OO (and nothing is being patched; when one descends from a parent class, the parent is left alone untouched).

Comment: I didn't mean the technique, i meant the whole idea. It is exactly the same in both cases: Have module XYZ act like module ABC, only with one piece changed.

Comment: @mithaldu: I see at least two differences: 1. leaving the parent unmodified 2. having the ability to tackle something on top of what the parent method does, instead of having to override it entirely.

Comment: I think i'm just complaining because this code i have here is ugly and i should stop now. Thanks for the input. :)

Comment: @mithaldu: I feel your pain! Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
package Local::Patched::Foo;
use Foo qw/:all_without_qux/; #see Exporter docs for tags or just list all functions
use Exporter 'import'; #modern way
our @EXPORT = qw( baz [... 100 more functions here ...] qux);
sub qux { print 2; }
1;
```

Comment: This does not work. baz() in script.pl still calls Foo::qux() instead of Local::Patched::Foo::qux().

Comment: It shouldn't, as long as you `use Local::Patched::Foo` in script.pl without `use Foo`.

Comment: Did you run it successfully then? If so, could you possibly post a working file constellation on gist.github? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you *replace* the offending file.

```
mkdir Something
cp Something.pm Something/Legacy.pm # ( or /Old.pm or /Bad.pm )
```

And then go in to that file and edit the package line:

```
package Something::Legacy;
```

Then you have a place to step in front of the legacy code. Create a new Something.pm and get all it's exports:

```
use Something::Legacy qw<:all>;
our @EXPORT      = @Something::Legacy::EXPORT;
our @EXPORT_OK   = @Something::Legacy::EXPORT_OK;
our %EXPORT_TAGS = %Something::Legacy::EXPORT_TAGS;
```

After you have all that in your current package, just re-implement the sub.

```
sub bad_thing { ... }
```

Anything your legacy code that calls `Something::do_something` will be calling the old code *via* the new module. Any legacy code calling `Something::bad_thing` will be calling the new code.

As well, you can manipulate `*Something::Legacy` in other ways. If your code does not uses a local call, you're going to have to clobber `&Something::Legacy::bad_thing`.

```
my $old_bad_thing = \&Something::Legacy::bad_thing;
*Something::Legacy::bad_thing = \&bad_thing;
```

Thus `bad_thing` is still allowed to use that behavior, if desired:

```
sub bad_thing { 
    ...
    eval { 
        $old_bad_thing->( @_ );
    };
    unless ( $EVAL_ERROR =~ /$hinky_message/ ) { 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```